# Ender 3 Pro Weak Prints after Cura upgrade

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3

I'm getting weak prints on Ender 3 Pro with Cura after Cura upgrade.

Prints on my Ender 3 Pro have been good until I was forced to update Cura due to having to update the OS on my laptop.  Now my prints are weak even after using Infill 50 % from 20 %.

Upgraded to Cura 4.8.0.

I noticed that it seems my print settings were saved from the older non-working Cura version.  I went ahead and printed an XYZ Cube with the same settings from my older Cura version where prints were printing fine/acceptable.  It fell apart as I tried to lift it off the build plate so I printed a second XYZ Cube with 50 % infill from previous 20 % pictured below:

[image]

The above print is noticeably weak, with layers not bonding or maybe something else.

Below is an image of when an XYZ Cube printed with my older Cura version.  It is not perfect but it is much stronger without visible separation and actually noticeably heavier than the grey XYZ Cube printed with Cura 4.8.0 :

[image]

The green and the grey 1.75 mm PLA I use and shown in the photos are different brands but both printed very much the same with the older Cura version.

I'm thinking this is an issue with the new Cura 4.8.0 that I'm using as nothing about my printing has changed besides the new Cura version assuming that my original print settings were saved which it looks to me that they were.

Has anyone had a similar issue or is there a known fix for this?

---

*Posting settings pics below:*

[image]

[image]

12/28/20 :
Went to https://www.chepclub.com/cura-profiles.html and noted that they mention to use the Cura 4.8.0 Built-In profiles.  Below are two pics of test print while using Cura 4.8.0's Built-In Standard Profile :

[image: Cura 4.8.0 Standard Profile]

[image: Cura 4.8.0 Standard Profile]

12/29/20 :

Screenshot showing Nozzle Diameter (still using the 0.4 mm stock nozzle) & Flow @ 100 %.  Please let me know if these are not the correct settings you asked me to look in :

[image]

Comment: You are experiencing severe under-extrusion. Usually this is a filament diameter problem, this has nothing to do with the infill percentage. Please look into the filament diameter again (post screenshot) and check the extrusion multiplier.

Comment: @wallwalker You could try a different profile just to test, e.g. from [chepclub.com](https://www.chepclub.com/cura-profiles.html). It is not impossible that a problem with the printer happened at just the same time as you changed Cura version.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. Tried a profile suggested by chepclup.com.  Still not good results.  Again, my printer was working perfectly fine until I was forced to upgrade to Cura 4.8.0.  After using my tried an true profile with the new Cura, I started getting these poor print results.

Comment: @0scar Sounds like you said my diameter setting is OK but I need to check if a flow modifier is active.  Would I check for that in Preferences > ?

Comment: If you install an older version, the cube prints fine? Also, did you measure the filament with a caliper? What worries me is that the latest added image suggest a different possible problem, the higher up the cube the worse the quality, heat creep? Please also check (long shot as that usually gives even more sparse filament deposition) that your printer is not set into volumetric flow printing: option in the menu of your firmware.

Comment: Issue Resolved : Some custom PLA setting in Cura was selected instead of Generic PLA .  Prints good again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Total user error on my end.  With the new version of this app somehow I did not catch that material selected on the UI dropdown was set to some custom material and not Generic PLA.  Once I selected the proper material, all worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are three settings you will want to check in Cura to help with this.

**Nozzle Diameter**

Check your "Nozzle Diameter" if you've moved to a larger nozzle and haven't changed it in the new Cura version then it'll be under-extruding, or the default option may just be incorrect for you, most printers (Like the stock Ender 3 Pro) use a 0.4 mm nozzle.

**Flow Rate**

Flow rate usually requires a calibration test, however you should reference your old Cura profile for this, if in doubt, 100 %.

**Filament Diameter**

This needs to be set to 1.75 mm on almost every printer, which yours is.

If you can't get it figured out with these, generate G-code With two versions of Cura side-by-side.